# How to send data in GET request in django rest api test

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

There are "Consultant" and "Price" tables in DB and "Price" has a foreign key to "Consultant". I want to get all price records that are related to specific consultant. But I get an error when I use `APITestCase` to send GET request.

views.py:

```
class PriceAPI(APIView):
    serializer_class = PriceSerializer
    def get(self, request):
        consultant_type = request.data.get('type', None)
        try:
            consultant = Consultant.objects.get(user=request.user, type=consultant_type)
        except Consultant.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
        try:
            serializer = self.serializer_class(consultant.prices, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

test.py:

```
class PriceTest(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        ###
    def test_get_delete_price(self):
        response = self.client.get(
            reverse('price'),
            data=json.dumps(
                {'type': 'sports'}),
            content_type='application/json'
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I get this error:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\programming\Pycharm\Projects\Django Projects\CAPP\capp_api\tests.py", line 394, in test_get_delete_price
    content_type='application/json'
  File "D:\programming\Pycharm\Projects\Django Projects\CAPP\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\test.py", line 286, in get
    response = super().get(path, data=data, **extra)
  File "D:\programming\Pycharm\Projects\Django Projects\CAPP\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\test.py", line 194, in get
    'QUERY_STRING': urlencode(data or {}, doseq=True),
  File "D:\programming\Pycharm\Projects\Django Projects\CAPP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\http.py", line 113, in urlencode
    for key, value in query:
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

This error is about data that is sent in request. How can I do that in GET request?

Comment: GET arguments are not passed as JSON body but as query string parameters in URL

Comment: But, it is okay to pass JSON payload in HTTP get requests, isn't it?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Yes, it's ok in HTTP get request

Answer (score 3):

GET request can't pass JSON body. Parameters can pass by query string.
So in test.py data must change and in "get" function in views.py by `request.GET.get('field')` we can access to that parameter.

test.py:

```
response = self.client.get(
    reverse('price'),
    data={'type': 'sports'},  # This line is changed
    content_type='application/json'
)
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

views.py:

```
consultant_type = request.GET.get('type', None)
```

Answer (score 0):

this:

```
'QUERY_STRING': urlencode(data or {}, doseq=True),
```

makes me think that `data` should be a dictionary, but you're using `json.dumps()` to convert it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of =>

```
payload = {"uid": "123456"}
result = client.get(
         "/records/get-ownership-data/", data=payload
        )
```

You have option to format directly with f-string=>

```
uid_value = "123456"
result = client.get(
            f"/records/get-ownership-data/?uid={uid_value}"
        )
```

and then to read:

```
 result = request.GET.get("uid_value", None)
```

I think it's more about readability. Second option is more explicit about fact that we are adding like query parameter.